# How to Assign Members of Generic Type in the Constructor of a Generic Type?

Tags: c#, generics

How do I assign a value in a generics C# class?

```
public class GeneralWrapper<T>
{
    public GeneralWrapper()
    {
       Datas = new ?
    }

    public T Datas { get; set; }
}
```

I'm writing a generic wrapper class for a List objects (any object). So I can use this class like

```
GeneralWrapper<List<string>> _wrapper = new GeneralWrapper<List<string>>();
_wrapper.Datas.Add("hello")
```

but the Datas need to be automatically initialized in the constructor like

```
Datas = new Datas<t>();
```

it seems so that I don't have to create new after I create the GeneralWrapper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class GeneralWrapper<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public GeneralWrapper()
    {
       Datas = new T();
    }

    public T Datas { get; set; }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx Has the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on your generic type:

```
public class GeneralWrapper<T> where T: new()
{
    public GeneralWrapper()
    {
       Datas = new T();
    }

    public T Datas { get; set; }
}
```

The `new()` constraint indicates that `T` must be a type that posses a default, parameterless constructor. This is verified at compile-time and allows you to instantiate this object from within the generic class.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to create instances of generic type parameters in C# is pretty limited.  By default you really only have a few options

- Constrain `T` to `new()` which allows `new T()`
- Constrain `T` to `class` which allows `null`
- Use `default(T)` which works for all `T` values

Here though it looks like you want to use complex constructors (those which take at least one parameter).  There is no way to do this directly in C#.  Instead you need a more indirect mechanism like a delegate / lambda or a factory pattern.

In this case though it just looks like you want to assign an initial value to `Datas`.  Given that it's a public property the likely best approach is to do nothing and allow the consumer to use an object initializer to set the property themselves.  For example.

```
var x = new GeneralWrapper<MyType>() {
  Datas = new MyType("hello", "world");
};
```

Or if you want the value to always be assigned then force them to pass the value to the constructor

```
public GeneralWrapper(T datas) {
  Datas = datas;
}
```